# In Python, how does a for loop with `range` work?

Tags: python

```
for number in range(1,101): 
    print number
```

Can someone please explain to me why the above code prints 1-100? I understand that the range function excludes the last number in the specified range, however, what is the 'number' part of the syntax?

I am more used to C++ & Java where I'd write the code like:

```
for (i = 1; i < 101; i++) {
   System.out.println(i);
   i++;
}
```

So what exactly is 'number'? I'm sure i'm looking too far into this and there is a simple question.

Comment: That Java/C++ snippet will stop executing before the first `i++` because of the `return`.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

`number` is equivalent to `i` in your C loop, i.e., it is a **variable** that holds the value of each loop iteration.

A simple translation of your Python code to C would result in something along these lines:

```
for (int number = 1; number < 101; number++) {
  printf("%d\n", number);
}
```

Comment: Thanks man. That makes it easier. What is the incrementation process?

Comment: range() returns a sequence (an abstraction that behaves like a list of numbers), and 'for number in...' is said to 'iterate over the sequence'. There's no exact analog to the sequence in the C version, but the relationship between the elements of the range sequence is where the 'incrementation' happens.

Answer (score 10):

[Python 2.7 documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html) states:

> range([start], stop[, step])¶
>
> This is a versatile function to create
>   lists containing arithmetic
>   progressions. It is most often used in
>   for loops. The arguments must be plain
>   integers. If the step argument is
>   omitted, it defaults to 1. If the
>   start argument is omitted, it defaults
>   to 0. The full form returns a list of
>   plain integers [start, start + step,
>   start + 2 * step, ...]. If step is
>   positive, the last element is the
>   largest start + i * step less than
>   stop; if step is negative, the last
>   element is the smallest start + i *
>   step greater than stop. step must not
>   be zero (or else ValueError is raised)

EDIT: You may also want to look at [xrange](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#xrange).
EDIT: So basically:

```
for ( start ; stop ; step )
range( start, stop, step ) // where start and step are optional
```

Answer (score 1):

As JG said, number is your variable (much like `i` in your C code). A for loop in python is really like a foreach loop in C# (I think Visual C++ has it too). Basically, it iterates over a container. So you can use that syntax with lists too:

```
fib = [0,1,1,2,3,5,8]
for number in fib:
    print number
```

A range object acts sort of like a container, containing all the numbers between a and b.

Answer (score 1):

This is a slightly confusing issue for new programmers in Python that have experience in object-oriented or procedural languages (c, Java etc.)

The difference between those languages is that Python does not support a "counting"-like for iteration that is constantly used in C,Java etc :

```
for(i = 0; i < 10; i++){
...
}
```

In contrast, Python implements only a for that is similar to the Iterator interface of object-oriented languages (Java programmers will be familiar with this) :

```
for object in object_list
    ....
```

So, in your example  "range"[1,101] is the list (object_list) containing all numbers from 1 to 100 and "number" is the iterator (object) that takes the place of each one number

Answer (score 0):

number is a variable in which each value in the range is placed.

range actually returns an iterator, and the for is responsible for advancing it through the range.

Answer (score 0):

range is the list of the numbers 1 to 100.

`number` then references each object in that list