# Converting ip to binary

Tags: python, python-3.x, binary, ip

I am trying to convert 4 entered octets of an IP address into their binary form. This is only part of the code for converting the first octet into its 8 bit form. 'oc' is octet - I will fix variable names when I get this working.

```
remainder = 0

bits = (128,64,32,16,8,4,2,1)

binary = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]

oc = int(input("Enter oc1: "))
if oc > 256:
    print("Only 256 or less")

if oc > bits[0] or oc == bits[0]:
    binary[0] = 1
    remainder = remainder + oc - bits[0]
    print(binary)
    print(remainder)
elif oc < bits[0]:
    binary[0] = 0
    print(binary)

if remainder > bits[1] or remainder == bits[1]:
    binary[1] = 1
    remainder = remainder - bits[1]
    print(binary)
    print(remainder)
elif oc < bits[1]:
    binary[1] = 0
    print(binary)

if remainder > bits[2] or oc == bits[2]:
    binary[2] = 1
    remainder = remainder - bits[2]
    print(binary)
    print(remainder)
elif oc < bits[2]:
    binary[2] = 0
    print(binary)
```

When I enter 128 or greater as the octet I get a successful output.

E.g.: Entering '192' will display '1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0' but anything below 128 and the output is all zeros.

I am sure, I could use a loop for most of this as well but do not know how.

Comment: Have you looked at [ipaddress](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ipaddress.html#module-ipaddress)?

Comment: i dont see anything about converting an ip to its binary form.. just trying to create this program for a the convenience it'll bring when converting ip to binary @PeterWood

Answer (score 2):

Will this work for you?

```
oc = int(input("Enter oc1: "))
if oc > 256:
    print("Only 256 or less")
else:
    binary = bin(oc)[2:]
```

bin() converts an integer to binary, and using the [2:] appendage drops the leading '0b' you would otherwise get.

If you want to ensure that you have 8 characters, with leading zeros, you can use zfill(). As another appendage, zfill(n) will add leading zeros until your string is n characters long.

```
binary = bin(oc)[2:].zfill(8)
```

Comment: being new to python, this method took me by surprise! is there any way to keep the most significant zeros, seeing as there should be 8 bits when converting ip to binary? @Tom thanks!

Comment: Yup, use zfill(). I edited my answer to include it. You should also probably consider including a `if oc < 0: print('Non-negatives only')`, lest the [2:] will not work perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

Convert a IPv4 address to binary :

```
ip=raw_input("Enter the ip address\n") #input the ipv4 address
ips=ip.split('.') #split by '.'

for i in ips:  #ips is a list of octets,
 ##we parse through the list to convert each of these to binary
    print(format(int(i),'08b')) #Use format '08b' to add leading '0' to form '8' digits of binary 'b'
```

Input :

```
192.95.01.56
```

Output:

```
11000000
01011111
00000001
00111000
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution given by @Tom seems most appropriate. But if you want to go to basic school mathematics of converting decimal to binary, one solution is this.

```
import sys

string = "127.0.0.1"
oc = string.split(".")
for i in range(0, 4) :
   num = int(oc[i]) 
   j = 0;
   remlist = []
   while num > 0 :
       rem = num % 2
       j = j + 1
       remlist.append(rem)
       num = num / 2

   for x in range(j, 8) :
       remlist.append(0)    
   for element in reversed(remlist) :  
       print element,
   if i < 3 :
       print ".",
```

Comment: python loops confuse me.. what exactly does the 'i' in 'for i in range(0, 4):' mean?

Comment: python loops confuse me.. what exactly does the 'i' in 'for i in range(0, 4):' mean? @mayankTUM

Comment: The function string.split(".") parses the string into an array of strings of size 4. range(0,4) returns a list of integers [0,1,2,3] and 'i' is simply the iterator that loops through all these values. Similar to "for(i = 0; i<4; i++)" in c or java.

Comment: so the string.split(".") produces the 4 numbers in string without the "."? and if i had this code:

train = 1,2,3

for name in train:
 value = name*10

print(value)

what does 'name' stand for in 'for name'?

this is an example i saw a while back @mayankTUM

Comment: if I understood your question correctly, name will take the value 1 first, then 2 and so on. You will get 10,20,30 as the output.

Comment: so name goes to each value in train and * by 10.. ill admit i dont really understand the code you gave me so well, but im definitely going to study it because it works!! thank you @mayankTUM

Comment: Further help on `for x in range()` style structure is available at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3242314/in-python-how-does-a-for-loop-with-range-work)

Comment: ive been looking through your code and figuring it out.. quick question tho, if i enter, say, '192' as the first octet... when it gets to the while loop and runs through, which it will do 8 times, the 7th time, 'num' = 3, and when you divide 3 by 2 you get 1.5, but it makes the value of num '1' instead.. is this because earlier in the for loop, num is declared as an integer? causing any numbers after the decimal point to be removed?@mayankTUM

Comment: That is correct. From [the docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#typesnumeric), `For (plain or long) integer division, the result is an integer. The result is always rounded towards minus infinity: 1/2 is 0, (-1)/2 is -1, 1/(-2) is -1, and (-1)/(-2) is 0.`