# Loop for in Python with php

Tags: python

How to do loop like: `for(i = 0; i < 100; i++)`?

This code is in PHP, i want create this loop like in Python 3x.

Thanks my brothers for any what you do for me.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3.4/reference/compound_stmts.html#for

Comment: possible duplicate of [In Python, how does a for loop with \`range\` work?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3242314/in-python-how-does-a-for-loop-with-range-work)

Answer (score 2):

Use the built-in range function which takes an optional step and an interval `[a, b)` like so:

```
for i in range(0, 100, 1):
    # do something
```

Comment: As seen in Vaibhav's answer, you can condense to one argument but I wanted to show you the existence of three, two of which are optional.

Answer (score 2):

A range based for loop in python is not equivalent to C like for loop that is prevalent in javascript, php or languages as such which supports them. Particularly, the distinction comes in

- when the need comes to change the iterator variable inside the loop block
- Condition is more complex beyond a limiting condition

Ideally the best alternative is to re-write the `for loop` to a `while loop` in the similar way as you would have written in languages that supports both. For example

```
for(<initializer>; <cond>; <increment>) {
    // Loop Body
}
```

should equivalently be written as

```
<initializer>
while cond:
    <Loop Body>
    <increment>
```

so in your particular case, the equivalent of the php `for(i = 0; i < 100; i++)` construct in python would be

```
i = 0
while i < 100:
    # Loop Body
    i += 1
```

Using any other construct might have some surprising consequences.

Comment: Based on the example in the OP, he intends for a static, fixed loop. So range would be acceptable unless there is an unpredictable assignment of    the sentry in the loop.

Comment: @MalikBrahimi: We have not seen is entire code, so whether it is sufficient would be too early to predict. Range based loop is equivalent to a `foreach` loop, that most modern languages supports to a varied way.

Answer (score 0):

```
for i in range(100):
    # code here
```